# How does variable capture work with lambdas and functions in python?

Tags: python, lambda

I am very confused by this code:

```
def run_test():
    lambda_list = []
    for x in ["a", "b", "c"]:
        def print_x():
            print(x)

        lambda_list += [(print_x,)]


    for (l,) in lambda_list:
        l()

run_test()
```

Which when I run produces:

```
c
c
c
```

I natively would expect that it would produce

```
a
b
c
```

Is there a way to have the variable be captured and not reset in each iteration?

Thanks,
/YGA

Comment: `def print_x(x=x):`.

Comment: (which is covered in detail in the duplicate and kind of a hack – I would recommend the function that returns functions, since there’s no risk of calling with an argument)

Comment: you should use a function factor, e.g. `def make_func(x): ....` that defines and returns the function, and then `lambda_list.append(make_func(x))`